# Solr Search Query is not working with AND and OR operators

Tags: solr, document, solr-query-syntax, solr-search

I want to build a solr search query to search documents with the following criteria:
the relation between the properties of same Content type should be AND, and OR between different content types

I tried this query:
`fq = {!parent which="+solr_doc_type:d_parent"} (+solr_doc_type:d_child + ( ( current_content_type_id:80 AND (+property_id:331 -item_property_value:16) AND  (+property_id:329 +item_property_value:*test*) ) OR  ( current_content_type_id:109 AND (+property_id:918 +item_property_value:30052) AND  (+property_id:702 +item_property_value:1) ) ) )`

and this query also:
fq = `current_content_type_id:80 or current_content_type_id:109`
fq = `{!parent which="+solr_doc_type:d_parent"} (+solr_doc_type:d_child + ( ( (+property_id:331 -item_property_value:16) AND  (+property_id:329 +item_property_value:*test*) ) OR  ( (+property_id:918 +item_property_value:30052) AND  (+property_id:702 +item_property_value:1) ) ) )`

but in both cases the result is not correct.

Any suggestion for optimizing the SOLR query?